# Combine a number of outputs into one variable?

Tags: ansible

Would it be possible to combine a number of outputs into one variable to pull information from

```
---
- name: Get info
  ios_command:
    commands: 
      - show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.10 | in ip add
      - show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.20 | in ip add
      - show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.30 | in ip add
      - show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.40 | in ip add
  register: results_info

- set_fact:
    info2: "{{ results_info.stdout[0].split(' ') }}"
```

I've tried a few different ways but seems that only one line gets saved in the output.

I tried the suggestion below... running from a playbook..

```
---
- name: Get info
  ios_command:
    commands: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - echo "show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.10 | in ip add"
      - echo "show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.20 | in ip add"
      - echo "show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.30 | in ip add"
      - echo "show run int GigabitEthernet0/1.40 | in ip add"
  register: echo_output

- set_fact:
   info: "{{ echo_output.results}}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ echo_output.results}}"
```

I get the error that

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible. I tried to run multiple echo commands in linux and able to capture all the results into variable. Here is what I tried:

```
---
- name: Test Ansible
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: echo
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
      - echo "Hi1"
      - echo "Hi2"
      - echo "Hi3"
      register: echo_output

    - set_fact:
       info: "{{ echo_output.results}}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ echo_output.results}}"
```

Comment: To help understand, please add how to execute this code (cmdline) and where to place this suggested code.

Comment: @dpetrini I updated the code with full playbook file. You can run the playbook from command line using following syntax:
ansible-playbook <filename>.yml

Comment: I tried to incorporate into my code, but getting an error when trying to run.

Comment: @jmyths, what is the error you are seeing? I can run the above code without any issues in my machine.